# Dynamic array of strings - C

Tags: c++, c

I have an array of strings defined like this:

```
char** arrNames;
```

Now I want to dynamically allocate a size to it.
I have a function that receives the new size and the array above.
It goes like this:

```
char** AddName(char** arrNames, int nNameCount)
{
    char** arrTemp;

    arrTemp = new char[nNameCount];
    ...
    // And later I change the pointer of arrNames to arrTemp
}
```

Now this obviously doesn't work. So what should I be doing instead?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using C or C++? new char... will work only with C++. With C use malloc instead.

Comment: I'm using a C++ compiler (that's how they teach us), so it should work

Comment: if you want to learn C, don't use `new` even if you happen to be (very unwisely IMO) using a C++ compiler to compile your C code. If you want to learn C++ then in real life don't use `new` for this either, use a vector. For the purposes of understanding how memory allocation works in C++ you could use `new` for this, but if you're supposed to be learning malloc/free for use in C, then you won't do so by using C++ new[]/delete[] instead ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want nNameCount strings, you need to allocate an array of arrays of chars (i.e an array of strings):

```
char** AddName(char** arrNames, int nNameCount)
{
    char** arrTemp = new char *[nNameCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < nNameCount; ++i) arrTemp[i] = new char[STRING_SIZE];
    ...
}
```

After this you can access each string with arrTemp[index]. Note that you still need to initialize each string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an working example of how to initialize Dynamic Array of Dynamic strings.

```
twoDStr = new char*[10];
twoDStr[0] = new char[10];

cin>>twoDStr[0];
cout<<twoDStr[0]<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, functions for dynamically allocating memory are `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()` and `free()`.

[`man malloc`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/malloc/) should give you more informations.

Comment: Gah, `valloc` is a legacy Posix thing, not standard C.

Answer (score 0):

> // And later I change the pointer of arrNames to arrTemp

For this to work properly, you'd need arrNames to be a pointer to an array.

```
char** AddName(char*** arrNames, int nNameCount) {
    //...
    *arrNames = arrTemp;
}
```

Don't forget to free any previously allocated memory arrNames might refer to!